# Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient is nil

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I'm trying to use TwitterKit framework for my iOS app (in Swift). But when I use `Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient`, it occurs an error saying `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Here is my code:

```
import TwitterKit

func getUserInfo () {
    let twUserID = "my twitter user_id" // This is not nil
    let client = Twitter.sharedInstance() // This is not nil
    let apiClient = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient // This is nil

    // This occurs an error
    // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.loadUserWithID (twUserID, completion: {
        (user, error) in
        if let validUser = user {
             println("Success!")
        }
        else {
             println("Failed...")
        }
    })
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Even on old Objective-C frameworks that haven't been updated with nullability attributes, you can use *Optional binding* to ensure that force-unwrapped `Optional`s have a value before using them.

In the example listed above, you can optionally bind to the value of `Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient`, like this:

```
if let apiClient = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient {
    apiClient.loadUserWithID (twUserID, completion: {
        (user, error) in
        if let validUser = user {
             println("Success!")
        }
        else {
             println("Failed...")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I added the code using _Optional biding_ .  Found `Twitter.sharedInstanc().APIClient` is always `nil`. Do you know why?

Comment: It says in the docs "This API client is configured with your consumer key and secret if they are available to the Twitter object (either via initialization of the Twitter instance or your application’s Info.plist)." Did you set up the API client? http://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Twitter/Classes/Twitter.html#//api/name/APIClient